# TCL output file 1

Tags: tcl

i have a smal tcl script to output text from a file

in test.txt is text:

```
---------------------------[list]-----------------------------------------
00.01 aaaa
00.02 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my tcl script

```
bind pub - !textlist pub:textlist

proc pub:textlist {nick uhost hand chan args} {
  set file [open /home/test.txt]
  set input [read $file]
  set lines [split $input "\n"]
  foreach line $lines {
    putnow "PRIVMSG $chan :$line"
  }
}
```

output is now :

```
<@t> !textlist
<@test> ---------------------------[list]-----------------------------------------
<@test> 00.01 aaaa
<@test> 00.02 bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
<@test> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
<@test> :
```

how can remove the last : in channel output?  In file test.txt is not new line after last line -----

Regards

Comment: The question title is not particularly useful, can this be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a file with two newlines:

```
aaaa
bbbb
```

The `split` operation using a newline delimiter will split the components
into three parts.   The last part is empty.

You can remove the newline before the split operation:

```
regsub "\n$" $input {} input
set lines [split $input \n]
```

Or you can change the way the file is processed:

```
set fh [open myfile.txt]
while { [gets $fh line] >= 0 } {
  puts $line
}
close $fh
```

(Also: your example code is not closing the file after reading it).

Comment: Also try `string trimright` for removing unwanted trailing characters.

Answer (score 2):

The `read` command actually has an option to discard the trailing newline at the end of the file. So, just change your "read" line to:

```
set input [read -nonewline $file]
```